# Change the result of column comparison

Tags: python, pandas

For example I have a df1 which consist

```
Name     Age
Mark     23
Lyla     25
Jose     20
Dianna   23
```

df2 is as follows

```
Name     Age
Mark     23
Mina     24
Janna    20
Jane     23
```

I want to compare these two files if a name exist in both files

```
df1[New Column] = df1.Name.isin(attendance.Name)
```

But on the  new column instead of the True or False result, I want it to be Exist or  Doesn't Exist.

Comment: `np.where(df1.Name.isin(df2.Name),'Exist',"Doesn't Exist")`  or `df1.Name.isin(df2.Name).map({True:'Exist',False:"Doesn't Exist"})` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if-else logic:

```
def compare(df1, df2):
    if df1.Name.isin(df2.Name):
        return "Exist"
    return "Doesn't Exist"
```